# Use different haar file in Marilena for AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, face-detection, haar-classifier

I'm using the Marilena port of OpenCV to AS3 and have it working fine with the included face.zip file that contains the haar cascade for a frontal face. I've downloaded some other haar xml files - one that finds the two eyes which is what I need. However when I load the file with the ObjectDetector, and draw the found rects, all I get are three giant horizontal rects and they never change. 
Also tried other haar files with similar results, the only one I can get to work is the one included with the package.
Has anyone gotten other haar files to work and did they need to be modified? Anyone have a working eye classifier they'd be willing to share?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at this: http://www.beyond-reality-face.com/app - they do some serious stuff - works great. Licenses are pricy but you might find it useful. Sorry for not commenting - too low rep.